# Move object relative to camera instead of moving camera relative to object

Tags: animation, camera

I have created a complex animation where the camera moves relative to a target object which does not move.
Now I would like to keep the same relative movement between camera and target object.
But the target object should move relative to the camera and the camera should not move.

Comment: C4D user here. I just had the same challenge and solved it with Xpresso nodes. The proper way to do this is to invert the local or global matrix of your camera and apply that do you object. I first tried inverting the XYZ coordinates (0,10,20 becomes 0,-10,-20), that works, but not with rotation. Changing rotation 10,20,30 to -10,-20,-30 is wrong. I'm quite sure Blender has a similar node or script based system to do that math.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by copying and manipulating the F-Curves in the Graph Editor.

Essentially, you need to copy the f-curves relating to Location (you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when you have selected them) and paste them into the F-Curves for the object (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) (you'll need to add a keyframe first to create the curves for the object).

Once you've copied the f-curves you can add a Generator modifier with a 1st order polynomial in the format `y = c + mx`, setting `m` to '-1' (so as to 'flip' the curve) and 'c' equal to an offset matching the difference between the coordinate of the Camera and your object at the start of the animation.

Once you've done this you should get the same (but opposite) motion between your camera and object - so all that's left is to remove the keyframes from the camera so that it remains static while the object moves in the opposite way to which the camera previously animated.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks a lot for that detailed answer. The problem with this approach is, that the camera rotation will get lost. Hence the scene which is viewed by the camera would change. My goal was actually to get the exact same rendered animation result. I thought about the problem again, and maybe it would be easiest to just render the object with a transparent background. Then I can just render a second scene  using a different camera motion and finally combine both rendered scenes. Anyway thanks for your time and advice. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: No worries. Yeah - this would only work if the camera isn’t rotating... although if the camera *is* rotating then I don’t thing it would really be practical to do it at all (as you’d have to be able to mimic the camera rotation by moving and rotating the object - which would be really complicated). Glad you’ve got an alternative solution - I thing that will be the simplest way TBH.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need to transform everything else by the inverse of the camera transform, and then stop moving the camera.  You can do this with a bit of set-up and a bake action operation.

Start by making two empties in the same orientation at frame 1.  Parent one to the camera with keep transform.  Give it a copy transforms constraint, world->world space, targeting the second.  Bake the action on the constrained empty ("bake action" operation), with visual keying + clear constraints.  This empty's animation data now contains the inverse of the camera's animation.  You can now delete the second empty.

Go to frame 1.  Unparent the empty with keep transform.  Parent all of the scene's root level objects to this empty with keep transform.  Delete all animation data for the camera.  Play the animation.

There are things to be careful of.  World space constraints or drivers are now being evaluated differently-- you've created a new space in which to evaluate everything, the old camera space.  Cameras can have scale data, which gets propagated to their children, even though it doesn't have any effect on the render (ie, make sure you're not scaling your camera, natively or inherited or constrained, before doing all that.)  FoV changes won't be transferred to the scene objects, and cannot be.  If you're switching active cameras, it's just giving you the inverse transform of one camera, not keeping track of the switch.  Subframe interpolation isn't guaranteed, so don't try to remap frame rate or use motion blur after the bake.  Physics are now being evaluated in a different reference frame, and so won't be the same.  Of course, one or more of these differences is probably why you want to do what you want to do, so at least one of those is a good thing, not a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

For rotation copy the camera rotations to an empty object placed at the camera location. Now parent the object to that empty.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)